# Query Azure MobileServiceSyncTable with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, azure, xamarin.ios

I currently have an Azure mobile backend working with my Xamarin.ios application. However, I am currently trying to Query my table when one column value equals a certain value and I want to return the whole row. It return the right amount of rows but I cannot actually access the information it has returned and it just return the class List. I cant seem to get tot he actual values its returning (if it is that is...)

Here is the method that queries the table and should return the value:

```
public async Task<List<EasyPm_TpPmResults>> RetrieveExistingData()
{
    //Initialize & Sync
    await Initialize();
    await SyncPmResults();

    var query = easyPmTpLocalResultsTable.Where(item => item.TurbineIdent == FormResults.TurbineIdentity);

    var results = await query.ToListAsync();

    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    return null;
}
```

I know it returns null currently but thats just until I get the method working. The below screenshot shows what prints to the console:

[image: Console Output during application run]

Hopefully someone can point out something stupid im doing!

Thanks
Jamie

Comment: it appears to be returning a single item of type EasyPm_TpPmResults from the table - is that what you expect?

Comment: Technically yes thats correct. However, the single item of type EasyPm _TpPmResults should contain the various results pulled from the sqlite table I believe... Unless im doing something wrong

Comment: Console.WriteLine(item); will not print out the values of each property, it just calls ToString(), which by default just returns the name of the class.  Use the debugger to inspect the properties, or explicitly call "item.Property1" etc

Comment: Wow! Cant believe I didn't realise that! Sorry for such a stupid question but thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine(item);` will not print out the values of each property, it just calls `ToString()`, which by default just returns the name of the class. Use the debugger to inspect the properties, or explicitly call `item.Property1` etc